# Google App Engine generates new type -> cast it to my type

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore

I am working with Google App Engine and Google Endpoints to load data from my Google Datastore.

My API method that has to download all of my Entities looks like this:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getAllEpisodes")
public List<Episode> getAllEpisodes() {

    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Query q = new Query("Episode");
    PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);

    List<Episode> list = new ArrayList<Episode>();
    for(Entity entity : pq.asIterable()){
        Episode episode = new Episode();
        episode.author = entity.getProperty("author").toString();
        episode.title = entity.getProperty("title").toString();
        //and so on
        list.add(episode);
    }
    return list;
```

In my EndpointAsyncTask I now try to get this List.

```
try {
        List<Episode> result = myApiService.getAllEpisodes().execute().getItems();
        return new Gson().toJson(result);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
```

But I am getting an error: `Incompatible types!  Required: com.stuff.Episode, Found: stuff.backend.appnameApi.model.Episode` So somehow AndroidStudio generates a new type for me, just for the API. **How can I get my List with the right type?**